# How to solve this second-order non-linear ordinary differential equation?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-analysis

In physics, the acceleration of an object in the gravitational field of a mass M (e.g. the sun) is given by

$a = \frac{G\,M}{d^2}$

or written in a more mathematical way

$x'' = \frac{G\,M}{x^2}$

with the derivation  ' with respect to the time.

Integrating once you get

$x' = G\,M\,\int{\frac{dt}{x^2}}$

But then what? I am really stuck on what to then next, or how to solve this problem. I want to calculate the relationship between the distance and the time it takes to cover this distance. So basically I am looking for an equation

$x = f(t)$

and how to come to this solution.

In the end I want to calculate e.g. the time it takes for an object to free fall from the starting distance at earth's location $x_0=150$ Million km with $v_0=0$ to the surface of the sun at $x_1=700000$ km?

The solution should be about $5.585\,\mathrm{x}\,10^6$ seconds, if my numerical integration python code is correct ...

Comment: What if the solution $x(t) = ?$ is not an elementary function?

Comment: See https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=x%27%27%5C%2840%29t%5C%2841%29%3DDivide%5BG+M%2CPower%5Bx%5C%2840%29t%5C%2841%29%2C2%5D%5D

Comment: Multiply both sides by $x'$ and integrate to get $$x' x'' = \frac{G M x'}{x^{2}} \implies \frac{1}{2} x'^{2} = - \frac{G M}{x} + C$$

Comment: If you want a fall to the center, you need a negative sign in the force. Use some numerical solver or more general visualization software to check if you got the physics right.

Comment: Maybe there is no closed solution?

Comment: You could try some limit of highly eccentric, thin Kepler ellipses.

Answer (score 7):

By **Lutz Lehmann** and **Matthew Cassell**,
$$x''=-\dfrac{GM}{x'}{x^2},$$
$$x'x''=-GM\dfrac{x'}{x^2},$$
$$\dfrac12(x')^2=\dfrac{GM}{x}+\dfrac12 C,\quad\text{where}\quad C=(x')^2\bigg|_{x\to \infty}.$$
If $C\ge0$ and $x'>0$ then
$$x'=\sqrt{\dfrac{2GM}x+C},$$
$$t=\dfrac1{\sqrt C}\int\dfrac{\sqrt{x}\,\text dx}{\sqrt{x+B}},\quad\text{where}\quad B=\dfrac{GM}{C},$$
$$t=\dfrac1{\sqrt C}\left(\sqrt{x^2+Bx}-B\operatorname{arcsinh}\,\sqrt{\dfrac xB}\right).$$
I.e. the moving is **infinite**.

If $C\ge0$ and $x'<0$ then
$$x'=-\sqrt{\dfrac{2GM}x+C},$$
$$t=-\dfrac1{\sqrt C}\int\dfrac{\sqrt{x}\,\text dx}{\sqrt{x+B}},$$
$$t=-\dfrac1{\sqrt C}\left(\sqrt{x^2+Bx}-B\operatorname{arcsinh}\,\sqrt{\dfrac xB}\right).$$
I.e. the moving is opposite to the previous case.

And if $C<0$ then
$$x'=\pm\sqrt{\dfrac{2GM}x+C},$$
$$t=\pm\dfrac1{\sqrt{-C}}\int\dfrac{\sqrt{x}\,\text dx}{\sqrt{|B|}-x},$$
$$t=\pm\dfrac1{\sqrt{-C}}\left(|B|\arcsin\,\sqrt{\dfrac x{|B|}}-\sqrt{|B|x-x^2}\right).$$
I.e. the moving is **finite**.

Comment: The "freefall starting from $R=1AU$" means that $x'(0)=0$ so that $C=-\frac{GM}{R}$. That $C$ and thus $B=-R$ are negative might change the integration formula, argsinh changing to arcsin etc. // The sign before the square root has to be negative for a movement towards the center.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Thank you! Detalized.

Answer (score 3):

Since this is actually a very practical problem, I will use notations that are used in physics.

I reformulate the problem as follows

**High altitude free fall**

(*no air resistance*)

Consider a planet with radius $R$ and surface gravity $g$.

Let us denote the initial height of a body above the surface of the planet by $H$ and the current height by $h\leq H$

The acceleration of a body at $h$

$$a=\frac{dv}{dt}=\frac{dv}{dh}\frac{dh}{dt}=-v\frac{dv}{dh}=\frac{gR^{2}}{(R+h)^{2}}$$

The last differential equation is easy to solve. Taking into account that at $H$, $v=0$, we get

$$v=R\sqrt{\frac{2g}{R+H}}\sqrt{\frac{H-h}{R+h}}$$

Taking here $h=0$ we get the speed $v_{m}$ at which the body hits the planet's surface

$$v_{m}=\sqrt{\frac{2gRH}{R+H}}$$

At $H=\infty$ we get an estimate of the  minimum speed of a meteorite before it hits the surface.

$$v=\sqrt{2gR}$$

For the Earth with $R=6370$ km and $g=10$ $\frac{m}{s^{2}}$, $v\approx 11 \frac{km}{s}$

The next step is to integrate

$$v=R\sqrt{\frac{2g}{R+H}}\sqrt{\frac{H-h}{R+h}}$$

Taking  into account that $v=-\frac{dh}{dt}$ we get

$$\sqrt{\frac{R+h}{H-h}}dh=-R\sqrt{\frac{2g}{R+H}}dt$$

This equation can also be integrated in a closed form. Taking into account that at $t=0$, $h=H$ we come to the end result

$$\frac{t}{\tau}=\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan\sqrt{\frac{R+h}{H-h}}+\frac{\sqrt{(R+h)(H-h)}}{R+H}$$

where

$$\tau =\frac{1}{R}\sqrt{\frac{(R+H)^{3}}{2g}}$$
is a characteristic time constant.

Taking $h=0$ we get time $T$  it takes to reach the planet's surface

$$\frac{T}{\tau}=\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan\sqrt{\frac{R}{H}}+\frac{\sqrt{RH}}{R+H}$$

OP wanted the time it takes for an object from the distance of earth to fall into the sun.

In that case $R=696,340$ km, $g=274$ $\frac{m}{s^{2}}$, $H=15 · 10^{7}$ km

The last formula gives the same answer OP reported us, $T$ is about $6 · 10^{6}$ seconds.

Answer (score -2):

Since the question of gravitational force is classic, so is the solution to this problem!  Let v= dx/dt.  Then $x''= a= dv/dt= (dx/dt)(dv/dx)= v dv/dx= \frac{GM}{x^2}$.
$v dv= GM\frac{dx}{x^2}$.

Integrating both sides $\frac{1}{2}v^2= -\frac{GM}{x}+ C$.
We can write that as $\frac{1}{2}v^2+ \frac{GM}{x}= C$ and, multiplying by m, the mass of the object, we get $\frac{1}{2}mv^2+ \frac{GMm}{x}= Cm$ which is "conservation of energy".  The first term, $\frac{1}{2}mv^2$ is the kinetic energy and the second term,  $\frac{GMm}{x}$ is the gravitational potential energy.

Comment: I want an equation that relates the distance with the time, so I can calculate the time it takes for an object from the distance of earth to fall into the sun. I am not asking about the energies involved or the final velocity.